# How to display excel data on powershell console using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to display excel data(text format) present across 10 columns in powershell console

But it is not working

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objexcel.visible=$true
$objexcel.DisplayAlerts=$false 
$workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\Desktop\commute.xlsx")
$worksheet=$workbook.sheets.item(1)

$usedrange=$worksheet.UsedRange

@{TIME=$worksheet.Range("A1:A10").text 
DEPART=$worksheet.Range("B1:B10").text 
REDS=$worksheet.Range("C1:C10").text 
TRAINS=$worksheet.Range("D1:D10").text }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you expect the incomplete `@[TIME=...}` to do?

Comment: I haven't used PS to read excel in a while, I learned CSV's were much easier. My guess is you may have to read the data, store it in a variable and then display in PS. I am not even sure I have my old script I used to use. I will have to check for reference

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the cmdlet Import-CSV? It will be much easier.
try the following:
`$Worksheet = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\commute.xlsx'`

It will create a Powershell object you can use and manipulate.

hope it helps you.